# Mapping single bean class to multiple tables in hibernate

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have developed a spring rest service which will accepts a json input and freeze the details in to database and return the status as json output. everything is working fine.

now i need to update the service with the new requirement, i will get address details of the user and i need to update the address table as well. My question is

1) How to change the input request currently my controller is as follows

```
@Requestmappping(value="/register", metod=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity userRegis(@RequestBody UserBean userdetails){

}
```

2) How to change the UserBean format. Currently it is mapping to one single table. Now i need to update the bean with address fields. and i need to map the address fields to new table.

please help on this.

Comment: Encapsulate the address information from UserBean and create an AddressBean? Also keep in mind that a User may have multiple addresses on file and an address may have multiple users associated with it.

Comment: @nixxbb i am currently submitting the request as {"challengequestion":"job","challenganswer":"answer"}. Now if i updated the bean as you suggested, how to give input request?

Comment: I over-thought the composition, unless you need to verify if the address already exists, the simple solution would be to make a list of addresses in the user class as @rohit has done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to in composition in OOP. So, basically user has address or addresses.

```
class User {
     ....
     private Address addres; 
     //private List<Address> addres;     use something like this if user has multiple addesses    
}

class Address {

}
```

And offcourse you would not want to map same bean to multiple tables or something like that. The above relation is simple parent child relation. Read [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)